# why wordpress can't run on my nginx?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    root /var/www/html;
}

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

cat     /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

When to input 127.0.0.1:8080  in browser.

[image]

When to input  `127.0.0.1:8080/wp` where my wordpress was built  in browser .
A file was downloaded automatcally,the file content is as following:

```
/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Why my wordpress can't displayed on nginx properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's deal with these issues one by one:

**1 - 403 Forbidden Response**

The reason you get this response is, most probably, due to insufficient permissions for your */var/www* directory.
Change these permissions like this:

```
$ sudo chmod 0755 -R /var/www
```

**2 - Instead of WP a text file (with BIN extension) containing PHP code is served**

This is because you either lack the proper package (*php5-fpm*) or there are some misconfigurations in your conf files.

First, make sure that anything inside your */var/www/html* directory is owned by the user *www-data*, like this:

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/*
```

Now, in case you haven't already, install the *php5-fpm* package with your distro's package manager. For Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-fpm
```

Next, you have to make some minor changes in 3 configuration files:

**A)** in */etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf*

make sure the following line exists, if not add it

> listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

**B)** in */etc/php5/fpm/php.ini*
find the following (probably commented by default) line

> ;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1

uncomment it and set its value to 0

**C)** in */etc/nginx/nginx.conf*

Make the following changes:

Add the following block of rules *inside* your server rule (right below the *root /var/www/html;* line):

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

---

And, finally, restart php5-fpm and nginx services.
In Ubuntu (without systemd):

```
$ sudo service php5-fpm restart
$ sudo service nginx restart
```

This should help fix these issues.

You can find (somewhat advanced) documentation on *nginx* and *Wordpress* [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx).